# Why does sampling the DataFrame of my entire dataset have better results in a prediction model than sampling my training set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, classification

Let's say I have a dataframe, called `original_df`, of 20,000 rows. I split the first 18,000 rows to be used as my training set and the last 2,000 rows to be used as my testing set. When I use the `sample` function on the `original_df` *before splitting* and run a classifier model on the training set, it produces reasonable prediction results: some false positives, some false negatives, some true positives, and some true negatives.

However, when I use the `sample` function on the training set and the testing set after splitting the non-shuffled `original_df`, the classifier is never able to make a positive prediction: I would only get true negatives and false negatives; and zero false positives and true positives.

I'm just trying to understand why this happens despite having the same sampling techniques, below are some example snippets.

```
# This example samples the original dataset directly

training_len = math.ceil(len(X) * 0.9)
X.sample(frac=1, random_state=2) # Features 
Y.sample(frac=1, random_state=2) # Labels
X_train = X.loc[:training_len]
Y_train = Y.loc[:training_len]
X_test = X.loc[training_len+1:]
Y_test = Y.loc[training_len+1:]

# fp, fn, tp, tn
# 1314, 1703, 455, 8842
```

```
# This example samples the training set directly

training_len = math.ceil(len(X) * 0.9)
X # Features 
Y # Labels
X_train = X.loc[:training_len].sample(frac=1, random_state=2)
Y_train = Y.loc[:training_len].sample(frac=1, random_state=2)
X_test = X.loc[training_len+1:]
Y_test = Y.loc[training_len+1:]

# fp, fn, tp, tn
# 0, 425, 0, 2518
```

I'm using `GaussianNB()` from `sklearn.naive_bayes`

I tried checking to see if there were any index mismatching between the training and testing sets, but it wasn't.

I tried to not sample anything from the training and original sets and it had the same prediction results as when sampling just the training sets dataset. This made me think that `X_train` and `Y_train` was not being shuffled at all, but I printed the contents of the training sets after sampling and they were indeed shuffled(with matching indices for `X_train` and `Y_train`).

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Is it not a programming question. I can rephrase this a bit and ask "how to make sample work when applied to the training set?", or "why doesn't my implementation produce0 'good' results"

Comment: Please notice that SO is about *programming* questions, and no matter how you rephrase this, it will not become about programming. Please also notice that you have been provided with further guidance in the form of a suggested link.

Comment: I can see where you are coming from in terms of removing the machine-learning specific tag and your interpretation of *programming*. This post was asking of the "why" and not on the "how". I was ultimately asking "why this particular programming implementation did not work but another did", which is a *programming* question imo. 

But I believe you were trying to encourage only "How" programming questions, such as "How to properly shuffle datasets in python". But in the end I agree with you in the removal of the tag, and will remove that tag :)

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood. Please notice that the issue of a question being on-topic here or not has to do only with the *content* of the question, and it has can never be resolved by tag manipulation alone; the idea was not of course to remove the ML tag (edited back), but to inform you about other SE sites where such questions *may* be on-topic. Please also notice that it is not me, it is the site rules.

Answer (score 0):

Is your initial dataset sorted by label? If so, in the second case your training set might be only one label (negative) and your classifier learns to just always predict that label.

Comment: Not sorted in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It's because I had to `reset_index()` the training set after `sampling`. If the row with index `training_length` is shuffled to be the first row of the dataframe, `X.loc[:training_length]` would only get all elements before and at the row with index `training_length` which would train my model with just one row; thus producing such bad results.